# multiple string matches within a single column

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am using isin() with pandas to find out the cars which have '10' or'hours' included in the 'condition' column of dataset. 
I am using

```
UScars.isin({'condition':[10, 'hours']})
```

but this gives me a system error.

```
SystemError: 'built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x000001F40BF30EE0' returned a result with an error set.
```

I used the `split()` on the condition column to convert the type from str to list.

I dont know where i am getting wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need `str.contains` using `|` operator to specify multiple string matches.

[pd.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) from the docs :

> Whether each element in the DataFrame is contained in values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,1,2],
                  'Condition' : ['10 Hours', '20 Hours', '30 Days']})

print(df)

   A Condition
0  0  10 Hours
1  1  20 Hours
2  2   30 Days



df[df['Condition'].str.contains('10|Hours')]

   A Condition
0  0  10 Hours
1  1  20 Hours
```